# Animation Help/ Animatior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to work on this shotgun for this gun in my game. I have done all the animation work for it but, it seems I have run into a problem. If I have to reload the entire amount of 6 I want to play the animation 6 times and if I shoot 3 bullets I want the Animation to play 3 times while reloading.

Again I have the animations down just trying to see how to replay the animations based off how many times I have shot, 
Kind Regards, SB

Answer (score 0):

One approach: your animation needs an event added to it at the end frame of the reload sequence.  This event will call out to c# code which will then decide whether to maintain the state of 'reloading' in your animator graph, re-running the loading cycle, or to change the animator to the 'idle' sequence.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "trigger" parameter [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cvco.png) to your animator and set to play animation by condition of that trigger [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjvvt.png)
You can launch your animation by using SetTrigger("triggername") command.